# SAS: Creating classes by enumeration

Tags: sas

that's probably an easy one.

I need to create a variable that is like an order but the order increases only after every second observations.

Thanks in advance!

```
date    order
1-1-10   1
2-1-10   1
3-1-10   2
4-1-10   2
5-1-10   3
6-1-10   3
7-1-10   4
7-1-10   4

etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be using two primary tools: The `mod` function and a sum statement. The sum statement looks like incorrect syntax, but it's a special case of `retain`.

`_N_` is a special variable that acts as your observation counter. Every time that your `data` step loops from the top to the bottom (that is, from `data` to `run`), `_N_` increments by one.

By using `mod` on `_N_`, we can increment a counter by one for every two observations where the result is 1. In other words, if you divide an observation count by 2 and get a remainder of 1, then add 1 to `order`.

For example:

```
_N_  _N_/2   Remainder  Operation    Value
1    1/2     1          0+1          1
2    2/2     0          N/A          1
3    3/2     1          1+1          2
4    4/2     0          N/A          2
5    5/2     1          2+1          3
6    6/2     0          N/A          3
```

Ultimately, we are doing an operation where we increment some value at a specific condition, carry it forward, and repeat.

How this code looks:

```
data want;
    set have;

    if(mod(_N_, 2) = 1) then order+1;
run;
```

Comment: Or since mod(int,2) returns 0 or 1 you could simply use `order+mod(_N_, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

In data step, you can use the automatic variable `_n_`, e.g. `ceil(_n_/2)`.

In SQL, `monotonic()` function can do the same job.